# Undefined value of a CSV cell in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, undefined

I'm trying to declare a function able to resit the single cells of a csv.

Until now I have been able to write this:

```
function csvTo2DArray(data) {
    return data.trim().split('\n').map(function(row) {
        return row.trim().split(',');
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'Database/tabella.csv',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
        dato = csvToArray(data);
        console.log(dato);
        console.log((dato)[0]);
        console.log(csvTo2DArray(data));
        console.log(csvTo2DArray(data)[1][1]);
    }
});
```

The problem is that line 16 prints 'undefined', can someone tell me how I can do it?

Comment: Well. If it's empty,  what do you want it to return if not undefined? An empty string?

Comment: But why is empty?

Comment: well. Lol. I could guess, but a better question is how do you expect anyone to answer that when you don't show any data?

Comment: It is a simple csv, formed by three lines and columns, what I expect to get from the code is that the cell of cordinate 1 1 is printed